# How to stop menu bar appearing in full screen mode when switch desktops?

Tags: unity, fullscreen, menu-bar, ccsm

In Ubuntu 16.04 with Unity I have multiple desktops enabled and several applications running in full screen mode (Firefox and terminal). When I switch from one to another the menu bar appears for several seconds what is very annoying - how do I disable it?

I tried to use Compiz Config Settings Manager/Ubuntu Unity plugin, and in menus settings set all durations to zero, but it did not help.

Comment: You can already switch between full screen mode applications using the keyboard combination Alt+Tab which shows large icons of the running applications in the center of the screen that you can click to switch between applications. Even though this works fine I would prefer a less hacky solution, but I need more information. What do you see when you switch from one full screen mode application to another. Is it the top bar that has the clock, volume control, networking indicator icon, etc.?